# Dijkstra algorithm expanded with extra limit variable

Tags: c#, algorithm, dijkstra

I am having trouble implementing this into my current path finding algorithm.

Currently I have Dijkstra written and works like it should, but I need to step further away and add a limit (range). I can better explain with an image:

Let's say I have range of **80**. I want to go from `A` to `E`. My current algorithm, works as it should, so it results in `A->B-E`.

However, I need to go only on paths with weight not more than the range - **80**, which would mean that `A->B->E` is not the option any more, but `A->C->D->B->E` *(considering that range/limit resets on every stop)*

So far, I have implemented a `bool` named `Possible` which would return for the single part of path (e.g. `A->B`) is it possible comparing to my limit / range.

My main problem is that I do not know where/how to start. My only idea was to see where `Possible` is `false` (`A->B` on the total route `A->B->E`) and run the algorithm from `A` to `A->E` again without / excluding `B` stop/vertex.

Is this a good approach? Because of that my big O notation would increment twice (as far as I understand it).

[image: dijkstra algorithm with limit]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see two ways of doing this

1. Create a new graph G' that contains only edges < 80, and look for shortest path there... reduction time is `O(V+E)`, and additional `O(V+E)` memory usage
2. You can change Dijkstra's algorithm, to ignore edges > 80, just skip edges >80, when giving values to neighbor vertices, the complexity and memory usage will stay the same in this case

Comment: I just finished coursera lecture of princeton univercity, so the algorithm is still in mind :) Highly recommended (https://class.coursera.org/algs4partII-002/class) :)

Comment: I haven't heard about edx, it looks nice, thanks for pointing

Answer (score 3):

Create a temporary version of your graph, and set all weights above the threshold to infinity. Then run the ordinary Dijkstra algorithm on it.

Complexity will increase or not, depending on your version of the algorithm:

- if you have `O(V^2)` then it will increase to `O(E + V^2)`
- if you have the `O(ElogV)` version then it will increase to `O(E + ElogV)`
- if you have the `O(E + VlogV)` version it will remain the same

As noted by [ArsenMkrt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/87053/arsenmkrt) you can as well remove these edges, which makes even more sense but will make the complexity a bit worse. Modifying the algorithm to just skip those edges seems to be the best option though, as he suggested in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20646419/2642204).

Comment: does he really need edges greater than 80 in the new graph?

Comment: yep, i think modifying algorithm is the best option, other options should be taken into account only if there is no opportunity to modify algorithm

Comment: Thank you both for the answers, but I will mark @ArsenMkrt's answer, because I really needed just a check for edges < 80.. which I am not sure why I didn't think of before. The thing is, I use the map with variety of ranges so having it always the same (not specific for 80/120/150) was important. Again, thank you both :)